# Out-of-memory error when scaling Dask arrays in a Dask cluster

Tags: python, memory-management, out-of-memory, dask, distributed-computing

I am encountering an **out-of-memory (OOM)** error when trying to scale **Dask arrays** using **StandardScaler** in a **Dask cluster**. The dataset size is moderate (~1GB), and each worker in the cluster has 64GB of RAM. I suspect that the scaling operation is not distributed across the cluster, causing memory limitations. How can I scale Dask arrays in a distributed manner to avoid OOM errors?

```
    # Create a Dask client with the desired number of workers (CPUs)
    scheduler_addr = "tcp://XXX:8786"
    client = Client(scheduler_addr)
    
    plkfile = 'XXX.bed'
    _, _, bed = read_plink(plkfile, verbose=False)
    
    y = pd.read_csv("XXX.csv")
    y = np.asarray(y['0'])

    X = bed[0:30000, 0:10000]
    y = y[0:10000]
    print(X.shape)
    print(y.shape)
    print('%.1f MB' % (X.nbytes / 1e6))

    X = da.where(da.isnan(X), da.nanmedian(X, axis=0), X)

    X = X.astype(np.float64)
    y = y.astype(np.float64)

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X.T, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, shuffle=True)

    scaler = StandardScaler()
    X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
    y_train = scaler.fit_transform(y_train.reshape(-1, 1))
    y_test = scaler.transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1))
    
    #Rest of calculation ...
```

**Expected behavior:**
I expect the scaling operation to be distributed across the Dask cluster, utilizing the available resources, and avoiding OOM errors.

**Solution attempted:**
I have tried using da.map_blocks to apply the scaling operation to Dask arrays. However, it seems that the operation is not distributed, leading to memory limitations and OOM errors.

**Question:**
How can I scale Dask arrays in a distributed manner to avoid OOM errors in a Dask cluster? Is there a way to parallelize the scaling operation using Dask and ensure it utilizes the available resources effectively?